# Cannot get files one folder up using glob pattern

Tags: yaml, kubernetes-helm, glob

I'm positive this is going to be something mundane, but can't seem to figure it out. Using helm I'm trying to insert all files in a folder one directory up into a `ConfigMap`. The glob pattern works fine if the folder is in the same directory as the `configmap.yaml` file, however move it one level above and it finds nothing. Below is the folder structure, below that is that yaml with the helm.

[image]

**configmap.yaml**

Screen shot to illustrate the path to the file:

[image]

Text:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: helm-configmap
data:
  {{ (.Files.Glob "../prop/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

Comment: Please don't post text as image, this makes it unsearchable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working directory of helm is the directory where Chart.yaml is located, so the relative path should be based on this.

So your configuration should be written like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: helm-configmap
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "prop/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

In addition, Some files cannot be accessed through the .Files object, usually for security reasons.

- Files in `templates/` cannot be accessed.
- Files excluded using `.helmignore` cannot be accessed.

> > [helm doc](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/)

Comment: Is it possible to access files that sit outsite the `charts_configmap` folder?

Comment: That's unclear also to me. @NealR have you ever found an answer?